# App crashes after taking a pic

Tags: android, camera

Need Help with this. Looked at many post but can't figure it out. Could someone please help me.

> Error - [ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/26698 (has
>   extras) }}]

```
    public int GET_CAM_IMG=2;
public int GET_GAL_IMG=1;

img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v){
    CharSequence[] names = { "From Gallery", "From Camera" };
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Select an option for updating your Profile Picture")
          .setItems(names, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (pos == 0) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                         android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);    


                        startActivityForResult(i, GET_GAL_IMG);


                    } else {


                       Intent i = new Intent(
                                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                   /**
                        i.putExtra("crop", "true");
                        i.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
                        i.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
                        i.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                        i.putExtra("outputY", 150);**/



                        startActivityForResult(i, GET_CAM_IMG);

                    }}}


            )
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                        }
                    }).create().show();
    }
    });}








    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    switch (requestCode) {

    case 2://Camera
        Log.d("take","pic");
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            Uri selectimage=intent.getData();
            Log.d("take","pic");
            img1.setImageURI(selectimage);




        }
        break;
    case 3://Selecting from Gallery
        Log.d("view","pic");
        if (resultCode == -1) {
             Bitmap bmp_image = null;
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                bmp_image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");



                img1.setImageBitmap(bmp_image);

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Logcat output:

```
08-21 12:46:46.269: W/dalvikvm(6566): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41096438)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/26702 (has extras) }} to activity {com.inspectreport6784/com.inspectreport6784.NewInspection}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3208)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3251)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:143)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4961)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at com.inspectreport6784.NewInspection.onActivityResult(NewInspection.java:169)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5363)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3204)
08-21 12:46:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6566):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: We need the stack trace from logcat to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `NullPointerException` on line `169`. Without knowing what line that is...

We know you're in this block of code:

```
Uri selectimage=intent.getData();
Log.d("take","pic");
img1.setImageURI(selectimage);
```

because your `ResultInfo` shows `request=2, result=-1`. That means your null pointer is in there.

The most likely cause is that `img1` is null. I see you use it above, but it's unknown whether it's in scope later. Without knowing how or when it's initialized, it's hard to say.

There's not much else that could be happening here. The only other possibility is that `intent` is null, but I don't count that for much. Your `ResultInfo` clearly shows an intent coming back.

---

In the future, you can find these things yourself in the logcat. Just look for something like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.inspectreport6784.NewInspection.onActivityResult(NewInspection.java:169)
```

For simple null pointers, it's very easy to narrow down. It gives you the file, class, method, and line all in one.

Comment: img1.setImageURI(selectimage); is the 169th line. how can i get it fixed. new to this java so will appreciate all the help

Comment: Then `img1` is null. Most likely it's out of scope. Try making it a class-level member. You may also want to read up on scope in Java.

Comment: hey , it worked , i put ImageView img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1); right above img1.setUmageURI(select image); now i have to figure out the orientation. it crashes when orientation changes but atleast i am getting the pic. your null pointer helped me. didn't know what it was until now